# How can I remove the need of wpcap.dll in my go program?

Tags: go, gcc, winpcap

I use gopacket in my program. on linux, it runs perfectly.
But on windows the whole program crashes if i did not install WinPcap before.

My plan was to check if WinPcap is installed, and if not to inform the user that he needs this to use 100% of all features.

But i dont come to this point. i cant use gopacket if WinPcap is not available. I mean... not a single line of code of it (=> crash)

Has anyone an idea how i can solve this? im do not need gopacket actually. My plan was, if it is installed, fine, super! If not, dont care... do other things.

But now i have 2 choices... remove gopacket totally or find a way to start my program without the need of wpcap.dll. at least to tell the user that he needs it.

Please help me :(

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're wrong in that you are «not [using] a single line of code of it»: it's not hard to see that
its [Windows-specific code calls into `winpcap.dll`](https://github.com/google/gopacket/blob/master/pcap/pcap_windows.go).

What is more fun, is that
its [Unix-specific code calls into `libpcap.so`](https://github.com/google/gopacket/blob/master/pcap/pcap_unix.go), and this means you have it working on your local system simply due to the fact you have `libpcap` package installed (or whatever it's named in your code).

All this means that currently your program is not really portable
anyway (I mean, in the sense you supposedly *think* it is portable).
You can run something like

```
$ ldd ./yourbinary
```

and see it printing a reference to `libpcap.so` of some version.

---

There are several ways to solve this.

The easiest is to just try shipping `winpcap.dll` *with* your binary. Windows by default looks for DLLs in the current directory of the application trying to load them. Since `gopacket` uses `cgo`, it means the `winpcap.dll` is attempted to be linked it at the application startup, so the application has no chance of changing its working directory before that library is attempted to be found and linked in.

A more complicated approach is to make (or obtain) a static version of the winpcap library (remember that DLL is a library, just a special form of it) and then jump around building `gopacket` so that it picks that static library.

Comment: do you have a good reference of how i can link a static library in windows? because i think that windows is ignoring all of my parameters (cgo, etc...) and it is very hard to find good info sources in the internet which works...

Comment: furthermore i do have already a static pcap link in linux. and this all works great... but windows is just.... *****

Comment: On WIndows, linking works exactly the same way (it even uses the same compiler (MinGW is a Windows port of GCC plus some stuff). I'd recommend you to ask on the mailing list for assistance.

Comment: it seems to be impossible. elastic beats (packet analyzer) also need winpcap preinstalled!

Comment: @Eric, that was long since I last touched packet capturing on Windows, but IIRC the idea winpcap gets installed—as opposed to just copied—into the system is making it available as a _service_ which you can activate (even remotely, via WMI) to capture packets non-interactively, w/o having an active terminal session (I mean, GUI). I won't swear by this, but I think you at least could try to verify this.

Comment: @Eric, as to the problem of statically linling a library, I would again suggest hitting [the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/golang-nuts) simply because a problem like this one calls for an extensive set of round-trips of information (you ask, we ask back for more info to narrow the problem domain back, you answer back, rinse, repeat) and are hence unfit for a Q&A site which SO really is (that is, one question—one answer).

Comment: @Eric, post there a message including an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (that is, a minimum possible Go program which would exhibit the misbehaviour you experience), your Go version, your OS version, and the full output of running `go build -x >build.log 2>&1` on it. Post the output of running `dir` commands on the directory hierarchy of your project as well. Then ask why it does not build what you'd expect it to.

Comment: @Eric,  one last note: the fact you have a `foo.lib` file _does not_ in any way _mean_ linking against it would produce a statically-linked binary: on Windows, `.lib`-files are so-called "import libraries", and they may refer both to `.a` files (actual archives with static code taken from `.obj` files) and to `.dll` files. It may be that this is exactly your problem after all, please re-check.

Answer (score 0):

Install [Npcap](https://nmap.org/npcap/) in "Wpcap API compatibility mode".